# Ruby selenium gem: open hyperlinks in multiple tabs

Tags: ruby, selenium

Goal: In irb, open a series of hyperlinks in new tabs and save a screenshot of each.

Code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox

browser.get 'https://company.com'
browser.find_element(:name, "username").send_keys("myUsername")
browser.find_element(:name, "password").send_keys("myPassword")
browser.find_element(:name, "ibm-submit").click

body = browser.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
body.send_keys(:control, 't')

parent = browser.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='someid']")
children = parent.find_elements(:xpath,"//a")

children.each do |i| ;  
  body.send_keys(:control, 't')
  i.click 
  browser.save_screenshot("{i}")
end
```

Problem: 
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up`

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can't share `WebElement`s across pages, yet you're trying to access `body` across multiple tabs. Try not to think of them as self-contained objects, but as proxies to something on a real page.

The solution is to only ever perform actions on the 'current' page. In your case that means sending the <kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> event on the tab that you've created. Having done that the first time, you're switched to the new tab. You then need to **re-perform** the  lookup:

```
newTabsBody = browser.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
```

and then:

```
newTabsBody.send_keys(:control, 't')
```

to create the next one. Continue for each child.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this, OP?

Comment: Perfect! I'll open a new question because one tab opens a .SVG where there's no "body" to close that tab. :-(